# Sweet finishing cabernet

Tags: red-wine

About 10 years ago I had a cabernet that was dry but had a sweet finish.

I've tried to find out what wine that was and have been unable to. Also online has turned up no results. Apparently this is an odd thing.

Does any one know of a dry red wine that has a sweet finish? I know it might be a bit broad but I would like to try literally any red wine that does this.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

It has taken a few years but I have found my answer. After talking to a sales clerk he explained what I was looking for was a wine that was "jammy". He recommended that instead of a pure cab, that I try a margaux and it did exactly this, dry in the mouth with a finish that seems sweet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a special cabernet sauvignon](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/7024/looking-for-a-special-cabernet-sauvignon)

Comment: I think the reason you aren't getting any answers is that the idea of a dry wine finishing sweet is simply contradictory. Perhaps if you try to use a different adjective for the finish you may get some responses. Perhaps "soft", "floral", "aromatic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, wine considered dry is allowed to have 9 gr (european unit) of sugar per Liter (european unit). 
THE ONE cab. you are looking for is most possibly at the end of that range.
Simply look for Cab. which is not so high in alcohol maybe 12%, not 13,5-15%.